# Area covered by Moving Circle?

Tags: geometry, area

Consider a situation where we have a point (x,y) moving on a 2-D plane. In fact, the point is function of time x=f(t),y=g(t). Centered around (x,y) is a circle of radius r? Obviously, we can visualize a circle moving in the 2-D plane. Compute the area covered by the circle from the the start of motion. Consider , f=t,g=sin(t) for non-negative t. Please consider the case in case the area covered overlaps.

Comment: This problem gives rise to a number of very interesting "integral geometric" quantities in the limit $r\to0$. See the seminal paper by Hermann Weyl, ["On the volume of tubes"](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~shmuel/AAT-readings/Data%20Analysis%20/Tubes/Weyl,%20volume%20of%20tubes.pdf). For example, the coefficient in front of $r^3$ in the volume of the $r$-neighborhood of a two-dimensional surface is proportional to the integral of its Gauss curvature (which is then related to the Euler characteristic). In fact, this observation led Weyl to the theory of characteristic classes.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but why wouldn't it be $L*2r + \pi*r^2$?

Comment: @level1807 This sounds rather new to me. Can you please indicate some introductory sources like Tube Volumes for Dummies and so on?

Comment: @Narasimham try Alfred Gray's book "Tubes".

Comment: @Narasimham Gray's books is the best reference on this topics but it isn't easy to read ( I have that book)

Comment: @fleablood it can be smaller than $L2r + \pi r^2$ when $r$ is bigger than radius of curvature of the curve or different part of the curve are closed to intersect.

Comment: I also found it that way ( as found on net)...that in spite of Mathematica plots. May he would revise had he been around :(.

Answer (score 1):

In 3D if length traversed by center of circle (or its center of gravity of a part ) with radius $r$  is $L$, then for the *Canal* surface area is:

$$ A = 2 \pi r L $$

It is the canal/toroidal/tubular area, by *Pappus' theorem.*

Comment: Pappu's thm is not only for surfaces/solids of revolution.

Comment: Oh, I was not aware of [this](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2316426).

Comment: Or so iirc, apart from surfaces of revolution ..

Comment: It's Pappus' theorem (i.e. the theorem attributed to a man named Pappus). His name was Pappus, not Pappu.

Comment: Ok,thanks, shall restore the correct appellation.